# How to Validate size and Dimension of Multiple Image Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have my coding

```
<table style="width:100%" border="1">

                             <thead><tr><td colspan="2"> <input class="form-control ImageClass" placeholder="" name="imageurl[]" accept="image/*" id="imagedurl" type="file" onchange="ImageValidation()"   value=""></td></tr></thead>
                             <tbody id="MultiImg"></tbody>
                             <tfoot><tr><td style="text-align:right" colspan="2"> <input type="button"  onclick="Addrow()" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add More" class="btn btn-success" /></td></tr></tfoot>

                              </table>
```

Once Click in the Add more button I will insert a new input field to upload a new file .here i nee dto validate all the files size and dimension , and my js is below

```
  $("#imageurl").change(function(){
  //    alert(this.files[0].size);
   var FileSize = this.files[0].size/ 1024 / 1024; // in MB
   //alert(FileSize);
      if (FileSize > 1) {
          alert('File size exceeds 1 MB');
          document.getElementById("imageurl").value="";
          return false
         // $(file).val(''); //for clearing with Jquery
      } 
      // alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
  readURL(this);
    }); 

    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $("#imageurl").change(function (e) {
  var file, img;
  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function () {
          wth=this.width;
          hit=this.height;
          if(wth > 1200 || hit>600){
              alert('File Dimension Should Not Exceed 1200X600');
              document.getElementById("imageurl").value="";

              $('#imgdiv').attr('src', '');

              return false;

          }
      };
      img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
    });
```

Below is my Code to generate the input fields

```
 function Addrow(){
  var table = document.getElementById("MultiImg");
 var x = document.getElementById("MultiImg").rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(x);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 cell1.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control ImageClass" placeholder="" name="imageurl[]" id="imagedurl" accept="image/*"  type="file"   value="">';
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-success" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>';
                              }
```

I have Done this for multiple images in javascript, But this not working

```
function ImageValidation(){
var fi = document.getElementsByClassName('ImageClass'); 
    if (fi.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= fi.length; i++) {
          alert(fi.files[i].size);
            var fsize = fi.files.item(i).size;      // THE SIZE OF THE FILE.
           alert(fsize);
        }
    }
                              }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes i need to validate all the files size and dimension, i have given by code but its not working

Comment: you should to include the behavior you're seeing vs. the behavior you want if you want a good answer.

Comment: Do you want to upload multiple images at once using single file input or you want to upload multiple images using different file inputs for each images?

Comment: i use different file inputs to upload multiple image @RopAliMunshi

Comment: Where is the code that you are using to dynamically generate the file input?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Added the code

Comment: `id="imagedurl"` = IDs must be unique.  So `$("#imagedurl")` always gives you the first image only.  Also `$("#imageurl").change` will only bind to the element that exists when it is called, any newly added elements will not have an event.

Comment: "Not working" **is too vague** - is it not calling the event (most likely)? - is it giving the wrong element?  Is it making your monitor explode?  It the calculation failing?  See: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @freedomn-m Pls check the updated code in js

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

`wth=this.width;`

should probably be changed to:

`wth=img.width; \\do the same for height to`

As the `this` object has no access to the `img` properties

Without knowing the actual error this was the first thing i saw that may cause some issues

Comment: while using 'this' is always dangerous, it will work in this case

Comment: Yeah, im used to seeing code like this in classes which have stricter scopes, im kinda just shooting in the dark, i still dont know what the __real__ issue is